# QField Create Geometry

Tags: qgis, geometry, qfield

I use QField for tree surveys. I use Geometry generator to create the crown (canopy) spread based on crown radius taken at N, S E and W. This works, but the crown is 'virtual' and cannot be edited. Rather than use 'Geometry Generator' or a 'Virtual Layer', I would like to automatically create the geometry in an editable layer. I'm aware QField does not yet support Python. But is there some other way of creating editable geometries based on the attribute values of a layer?

O